# Using ConTeXt \bTABLEbody and \eTABLEbody within macros

Tags: tables, context

I seem to have a problem with using `\bTABLEbody` and `\eTABLEbody` within macros. For example, I wanted to wrap these commands inside another command:

```
\def\BeginChemicalTable{%
  % ... other stuff goes here
  \bTABLE
    \bTABLEhead
      \bTR
        \bTH Chemical name \eTH
        \bTH Data \eTH
        \bTH Date \eTH
      \eTR
    \eTABLEhead
    \bTABLEbody
 }

 \def\EndChemicalTable{%
    \eTABLEbody
   \eTABLE
 }
```

When `\bTABLEbody` and `\eTABLEbody` are in different macros and I run ConTeXt, it halts and just leaves me at “Please enter a command or say \end” prompt, but when I replace `\BeginChemicalTable` and `\EndChemicalTable` with their respective contents and run throught ConTeXt again, it all works fine.

Am I trying to do something dumb, or are `\bTABLEbody` and `\eTABLEbody` known for not playing nice when in different macros?

Comment: Can you create a MWE? The standard way to do something like this is to use setups. `\startsetup chemicaltable %... other stuff here \stopsetup` and then `\bTABLE[setups={chemicaltable}] ... \eTABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t put the begin and end tags for table blocks in custom macros because ConTeXt uses `\eTABLEbody` as delimiter for `\bTABLEbody` when it stores the content. You can get around this problem when you use the buffer mechanism to save the content of your custom environment and pass its content to the body block of the table.

```
\def\startChemicalTable
  {\grabbufferdata[ChemicalTable][startChemicalTable][stopChemicalTable]}

\def\stopChemicalTable
  {\bTABLE
     \bTABLEhead
       \bTR
         \bTH Chemical name \eTH
         \bTH Data \eTH
         \bTH Date \eTH
       \eTR
     \eTABLEhead
     \bTABLEbody
       \getbufferdata[ChemicalTable]
     \eTABLEbody
   \eTABLE}

\starttext

\startChemicalTable
  \bTR
    \bTD XXX \eTD
    \bTD YYY \eTD
    \bTD ZZZ \eTD
 \eTR
\stopChemicalTable

\stoptext
```

The layout for the table should be as Aditya told better be moved into a `setups` block which can then be loaded with the `\bTABLE` command.

```
\startsetups[ChemicalTable]
    \setupTABLE[start][frame=off]
\stopsetups

\def\stopChemicalTable
  {\bTABLE[setups=ChemicalTable]
     ...
   \eTABLE}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still coming to grips with ConTeXt.